# Check if zip or rar archive is empty or corrupted with Php

Tags: php, zip, archive, rar

I have a very simple script that allows user to upload only .zip or .rar files. I'd like to know how do I know if a file is corrupted or empty?

This my script

```
if(isset($_POST['customerid']) && $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] && $_POST['requestid']){

            //post variables
            $customerid = $_POST['customerid'];
            $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
            $requestid = $_POST['requestid'];

            //check if the file is .rar or .zip
            $fileInfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
            $fileMime = $fileInfo->file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
            $validMimes = array( 
              'zip' => 'application/zip',
              'rar' => 'application/x-rar',
            );

            $fileExt = array_search($fileMime, $validMimes, true);
            if($fileExt != 'zip' && $fileExt != 'rar'){

                echo 'Not a zip or rar.';
            }

            //check if the file is corrupted or empty


            //if all OK insert file name and path to database
            $uservalida_stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO user_project_files (dateCreated,userid,projectFile,serviceRequestId) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
            $uservalida_stmt ->bind_param('siss',$currentdate,$customerid,$filename,$requestid);
            $uservalida_stmt ->execute();
            $uservalida_stmt ->close();

            //move upload and EXTRACT file to directory
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], '../user/project/' . $_FILES['file']['name']);

        }
```

Comment: Check out http://php.net/manual/en/refs.compression.php and post a new question if you run into an issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PHP manual has examples for zip. http://php.net/manual/en/zip.examples.php

```
<?php
$za = new ZipArchive();

$za->open('test_with_comment.zip');
print_r($za);
var_dump($za);
echo "numFiles: " . $za->numFiles . "\n";
echo "status: " . $za->status  . "\n";
echo "statusSys: " . $za->statusSys . "\n";
echo "filename: " . $za->filename . "\n";
echo "comment: " . $za->comment . "\n";

echo "numFile:" . $za->numFiles . "\n";
?>
```

or check the error codes simply on the `open` function (http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.open.php)

---

You can also do similar with RAR files (http://php.net/manual/en/rararchive.open.php) but will need to install it first (http://php.net/manual/en/rar.installation.php).

Comment: Hey thanks for this Robbie. So I'm guessing I would need to loop through the results to check all files individually? And if I want to check if there's a .exe file there I would check with $za->filename?

Comment: Be as thorough as you need. Checking if it opens would be enough to check validity, but you have the power to check for a particular file/size etc if you want to add extra validation. You can then customise your error messages "zip appears invalid", "file blah not found in zip", "file blah in zip is empty", "file blah in zip does not contain the right data".... go as far as you need.